# Retun list of checkboxes using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox, thymeleaf

```
  <p  th:each="accommodationCategory,accommodationCategoryStat : ${accommodationCategoryList}" >
  <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{accommodationCategoryList[__${accommodationCategoryStat.index}__].valid}" />
  <label th:text="*{accommodationCategoryList[__${accommodationCategoryStat.index}__].name}">label</label>
  </p>
```

AccommodationCategory class has two attribute valid and name. The form return list of AccommodationCategory. I can fill AccommodationCategory's valid attribute from checkbox, I want to fill name attribute using ${accommodationCategory.name} not from user input. I can't fill accommodationCategory's name attribute when post form.

Comment: Do you want to change the accommodationCategory's name using an input field?

Comment: No i want to fill accomodationCategory's name variable with accomodationCategory's name variable that come from model.

Comment: Ok, try using "${accommodationCategoryList[__${accommodationCategoryStat.index}__].name}" instead of "*{accommodationCategoryList... This is depending on your model, perhaps it's ok there and you should have:   <p  th:each="accommodationCategory,accommodationCategoryStat : *{accommodationCategoryList}" >

Comment: when I use  <p th:each="accommodationCategory,accommodationCategoryStat : *{accommodationCategoryList}" >, each didn't work.

Comment: Ok, the th:each it's ok, and changing the label text to "${accommodationCategoryList[${accommodationCategoryStat.index}].name}" gives you nothing?

Comment: My code now like bottom, it returns a list of AccommodationCategory class and it's valid attribute is OK, it can be filled with checkbox value. But I don't know how can I fill it's "adi" field. I want to fill this field with ${accommodationCategory.name} that came from model.

Comment: <p  th:each="accommodationCategory,accommodationCategoryStat : ${accommodationCategoryList}" >
                                    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{accommodationCategoryList[__${accommodationCategoryStat.index}__].valid}" />
                                    <label th:text="${accommodationCategoryList[__${accommodationCategoryStat.index}__].adi}" >Oda Kahvaltı</label>
                                </p>